# How can I enable the GUI on the Debian "Squeeze" Image?

Tags: debian, lxde, gui

The [downloads page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) indicates that this image includes LXDE, but I'm having trouble enabling it.

Comment: Most people that use lightweight systems have `go` script. They just run it when their computer boots up or logs in, and it starts all the GUI and other services.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you've logged in, just type `startx` on the terminal, then it should fire right up.

Answer (score 3):

To have the GUI run automatically when you boot your Pi, you'll need to install something like GDM (`sudo apt-get install gdm` - this is next on my list, probably this evening). Then to get to a text-only terminal, press `<Ctrl>`-`<Alt>`-`<F1>` through `<F6>`; and `<Alt>`-`<F7>`  to return to X.

Answer (score 0):

**Gnome**

You will need to install aptitude and tasksel before install gnome

Aptitude is an Ncurses based FrontEnd to Apt, the debian package manager.

Tasksel is a tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated “task” onto your system.

```
# apt-get install aptitude tasksel
```

Install gnome on debian

```
# tasksel install gnome-desktop --new-install
```

**LXDE**

minimum set of elements

```
# apt-get install lxde-core
```

complete set of elements

```
# apt-get install lxde
```

complete Debian LXDE desktop environment

```
# apt-get install task-lxde-desktop
```

You can choose more GUI from http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html