# Cannot connect to Xserver during CLI boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, python-3

so i want to autorun my python script after boot in a CLI boot however it seems that its giving me an error "Cannot connect to Xserver". My python script uses a camera i used crontab to autorun my python script.

Comment: How do you start the python script?

Answer (score 1):

If the GUI is already configured to run, you just need to set the DISPLAY environment variable in the script that launches your Python script.

If you're using `/etc/rc.local` just add `export DISPLAY=:0`. If you're using a .service file add `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` to the `[Service]` section (see [Raspberry Pi run commands on boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104282/raspberry-pi-run-commands-on-boot/104287)).

It might be helpful to make sure your script is starting as the same user as the GUI, in which case start `python` using `sudo -u pi python`.

If your GUI isn't starting, you may need to enable it or install it first. For the former, run `sudo raspi-config` and navigate through the "Boot Options" menu to the "Desktop / CLI" option, then select "Desktop" (see [here](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/maker/blogs/2018/how-to-boot-to-command-line-and-ssh-on-raspberry-pi)). For the latter, use the `tasksel` command and select Desktop Environment ([How can I enable the GUI on the Debian "Squeeze" Image?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-can-i-enable-the-gui-on-the-debian-squeeze-image)).

Answer (score 0):

If you boot to the command line the OS quite correctly reports "Cannot connect to Xserver" because there isn't one!

If your (unlisted) code needs **X** either boot to GUI or run `startx`